# Specifications for adding data to Scalar DLT's assets

Tags: scalardl

Does the time it takes to add data to the asset take a corresponding amount of time as the age gets longer?

Answer (score 0):

No. The number of asset entries won't affect the performance of appending a new entry to the asset in the currently supported database implementations.